# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Wi-Fi problems (network unclaimed)

Tags: 14.04, drivers, wireless, intel

```
$ lshw -C network
*-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 10
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d1300000-d1301fff

===========================================

gess@gess-Aspire-A515-41G:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

---

```
$ lspci -vvnn 
...
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2110]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 255
    Region 0: Memory at d1300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
...
```

I did:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Found that "unclaimed" typically means no drivers has attached to it. Next, I found and downloaded drivers for my Wifi (Intel 3168) and eject it (iwlwifi-...-.ucode) in `/lib/firmware`, reloaded the system and ... wifi doesn't work.

What should I do next?

*UPDATE*

In **About System** I have

Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on amd Carrizo

In the terminal:

`lspci`

```
$ lspci -vvnn
    ...
    03:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Lexa PRO [Radeon RX 550] [1002:699f] (rev c3)
    ...
```

`lshw`

```
03:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Lexa PRO [Radeon RX 550] [1002:699f] (rev c3)
root@gess-Aspire-A515-41G:/home/gess# lshw -C display
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Carrizo
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
       version: ca
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:234 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:d0800000-d0ffffff ioport:4000(size=256) memory:d1500000-d153ffff memory:d0200000-d021ffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: Lexa PRO [Radeon RX 550]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: c3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d01fffff ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d1200000-d123ffff memory:d1240000-d125ffff
```

I'm using 16.04.

[image: image-1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the classic dilemma, very new hardware and a very old kernel version. Your 8086:24fb device isn't supported by the driver `iwlwifi` until kernel version 4.6. You installed Ubuntu 14.04, a 3+ year old version that uses a much older kernel version.

I can write an answer that shows you how to experimentally, and with some peril, install the 4.6 kernel. However, I recommend that you instead install the Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS release that includes kernel version 4.10 and fully supports your device. You can certainly try the live session to be certain that everything works as expected. When you are satisfied, install it.

http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/

Comment: i tried installed 16.04 (from usb liveCD, made with "Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.7.9" .iso downloaded from official site (https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop))? but when the system starts up, it's hangs (black screen, maybe it's video drivers) ... I do not know how to fix it. 
What can you advise?
P.S.
 And I think you already understand, but just in case, this is my first experience with linux

Comment: Please try the live session from the link I gave for 16.04.3 and try again. Then tell me if it boots to a completely blank screen or to a blinking cursor. What is the video driver now under 14.04? Find out by looking at `driver=` when you run: `sudo lshw -C display`

Comment: I looked video driver (more info in update). Written "*-display UNCLAIMED" and no drivers, it's for discrete card ( so, means my PC don't use her, right?  ). For build-in graphics, drivers - amdgpu.

When loading version 16.04. She is stopped on next step - look "image-1" (from the update) (removed - "quiet splash", from startup settings )

Comment: Use `nomodeset` option, i have installed Ubuntu 16.04. Wi-Fi is work now (great), but video card has status "UNCLAIMED" ( and system don't loading without `nomodeset` ).
In the `Additional Drivers` has `microcode` (for AMD CPUs, and i can't install this) for `Unknown device`, which dosen't work (maybe it's video card). It's all what have the programm. Whats you advice, @chili555? **Video card model** - AMD Radeon 540 ( `lshw -C display` - no used drivers, `lspci -vvnn | grep Display` - `Kernel modules: amdgpu`)

Comment: Video is not my expertise. I'd suggest that you start a new question. Does the system work as expected otherwise? Perhaps *amdgpu* is all you need.

Comment: @ chili555, thanks a lot. I'm instaled the AMD drivers (amdgpu-pro), from the official site [link] (http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx) and all work correctly. I hope that this was continue. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working as expected.